# Generating 4 unique random numbers 0-8 in C

Tags: c

I need to generate 4 unique numbers from 0 to 8 and then add them to the array as characters. I tried this method I found online, but it changed the values to 48-55.

```
int main(int ac, char** av) {
    char winningCode[5];
           
           if(ac>2 && av[1][0] == '-' && av[1][1]=='c'){
               for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                   winningCode[i]=av[2][i];
               }
           }
           else{
               srand(time(NULL));
               
               for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
                   int random_number = (rand() % 8);
                   winningCode[i]=(random_number+'0');
               }
          }
    winningCode[4]='\0';
    printf("%d\n",winningCode[0]);
    printf("%d\n",winningCode[1]);
    printf("%d\n",winningCode[2]);
    printf("%d\n",winningCode[3]);
    printf("%d\n",winningCode[4]);
    int round = 0;
    char ch[6];
    printf("Will you find the secret code?\nPlease enter a valid guess\n");
    while(wellplaced(winningCode, ch)<4 && round<10){
        read_input(ch);
        if(checkInput(ch)){
            printf("\nRound %d\nWell placed pieces: %d\nMisplaced pieces: %d",round,wellplaced(winningCode,ch),missplaced(winningCode,ch)-wellplaced(winningCode,ch));
            round++;
        }else{
            
            printf("Wrong input!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Congratz! You did it!");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
52
50
54
55
0
```

Comment: `%d` outputs the integer value. You want `%c`, which outputs the character associated with that value.

Answer (score 2):

The `+'0'` in your code was adjusting the values to ASCII representations of each digit. When you printed the individual values using the `%d` format code, it printed the ASCII *ordinal value*, not the ASCII *character* it corresponds to. Change the format code to `%c` and it will work. Since you explicitly `NUL`-terminated, you could also print them all on one-line easily with:

```
printf("%s\n", winningCode);
```